# Identityserver 4 and Ocelot

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, api-gateway, ocelot

I'm trying to use Ocelot with IS4 following 
https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/authentication.html

When using

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var authenticationProviderKey = "TestKey";

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer(authenticationProviderKey, x =>
        {
        });
}
```

and use "TestKey" in ocelot.json, it throws an error when starting the application

*Unable to start Ocelot, errors are: TestKey,AllowedScopes:[] is unsupported authentication provider*

Any idea what's wrong? Do I need set up something in particular in my IdentityServer app?

Comment: On top of it, how can I secure my ocelot api gateway so that only the registered users can access the different endpoints, all that using IS4 + AspNetIdentity + EF

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the options, e.g.:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        // base-address of your identityserver
        options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io";

        // name of the API resource
        options.Audience = "api1";
    });
```

More info at: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html#

You will also need to add an API resource to your Identity Server:

```
new ApiResource("api1", "Some API 1")
```

See:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html and http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/api_resource.html#refapiresource